# Hand over "data/params" on reroute(); in "fat free framework"

Tags: php, routes, fat-free-framework

Im looking for an elegant way to hand over data/params when using `$f3->reroute();`

I have multiple routes configured in a `routes.ini`:

```
GET @sso: /sso/first [sync]  =   Controller\Ccp\Sso->first, 0
GET @map: /map       [sync]  =   Controller\MapController->second, 3600
```

Now I `reroute();` to `@map` route, from `first();`

```php
class Sso {
    public function first($f3){
        $msg = 'My message!';

        if( !empty($msg) ){
            $f3->reroute('@map');
        }
    } 
}
```

Is there any "elegant" way to pass data (e.g. `$msg`) right into `$MapController->second();` ?

I don´t want to use `$SESSION` or the global `$f->set('msg', $msg);` for this.

Comment: Rerouting implies that `second()` will be called in a subsequent request. How to share data between requests? Either by appending a query string or by using cookies/sessions. This is how the web works. Now what are you trying to achieve? If you want to display a flash message, go with sessions (also check [this plugin](https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/tree/master-v3/Flash)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an issue specific to fat-free-framework, but web in general. When you reroute, you tell the browser to redirect the user's browser page using a 303 header redirect code. 
Take a minute to read the doc regarding re-routing: http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine#rerouting

There seems to be some contradicting information in your question, which leads me to question the purpose of what you are trying to achieve.

If you are rerouting, you can either use the session, cookies, or use part of the url to pass messages or references to a message.

If you do not need to redirect, but just want to call the function without changing the passed parameters, you could abstract the content of the function and call that function from both routes. You could also use the $f3 globals, which are a great way of passing data between functions in cases where you don't want to pass the data using the function call. is there a reason why you don't want to to use this? The data is global for the single session, so there is no security concern, and the data gets wiped at the end of the request, so there is very little extra footprint or effect on the server.

Comment: thanks! My use case is a user /login path. In case the login was successful, user gets rerouted to to /map path (->reroute(); ), otherwise the /login route is shown again. I think $f3 globals are the best way to do it :)

Comment: Have a look at phproject,  specifically https://github.com/Alanaktion/phproject/blob/master/app/controller.php
it uses a MVC pattern, where all routes controllers extend this controller class. You just need to call the `_requireLogin` function from the consturctor of any class that has all functions require a user to be logged in.

Comment: In the link above, look at lines 35 and 37. these are used to designate where the user will be redirected once they are logged in. This is set up in such a way that one can go to any path requiring a login, be asked to log in, and redirected the to the same place. a `$f3->set` global does not pass data on between requests, only within the same requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you're alright with not using @map_name in re-routes you can do something like this:

```
$f3->reroute('path/?foo=bar');
```

Not the prettiest I'll admit. I wish `$f3->reroute('@path_name?foo=bar')` would work.